# Bokeh: run callback on plot init?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have the majority of my calculations for an interactive chloropeth graph done through callbacks on various attached widgets.

Can we run a callback on plot initiation? This could be accomplished by constructing a refresh/init button and attaching an initiating callback to it, but this still requires pushing a button.

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh version 3.1 added a [`DocumentReady`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/events.html#bokeh.events.DocumentReady) event that can be used for this. From JavaScript:

```py
from bokeh.events import DocumentReady

curdoc().js_on_event(DocumentReady, CustomJS(...))
```

or from Python (in a Bokeh server application):

```py
curdoc().on_event(events.DocumentReady, callback)
```